# asyncio tasks getting unexpectedly defered

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I've been trying to learn a bit about `asyncio`, and I'm having some unexpected behavior. I've set up a simple fibonacci server that supports multiple connections using streams. The fib calculation is written recursively, so I can simulate long running calculations by entering in a large number. As expected, long running calculations block I/O until the long running calculation completes.

Here's the problem though. I rewrote the fibonacci function to be a coroutine. I expected that by yielding from each recursion, control would fall back to the event loop, and awaiting I/O tasks would get a chance to execute, and that you'd even be able to run multiple fib calculations concurrently. This however doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's the code:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def fib(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    a = yield from fib(n-1)
    b = yield from fib(n-2)
    return a + b


@asyncio.coroutine
def fib_handler(reader, writer):
    print('Connection from : {}'.format(writer.transport.get_extra_info('peername')))
    while True:
        req = yield from reader.readline()
        if not req:
            break
        print(req)
        n = int(req)
        result = yield from fib(n)
        writer.write('{}\n'.format(result).encode('ascii'))
        yield from writer.drain()
    writer.close()
    print("Closed")


def server(address):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fib_server = asyncio.start_server(fib_handler, *address, loop=loop)
    fib_server = loop.run_until_complete(fib_server)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('closing...')
        fib_server.close()
        loop.run_until_complete(fib_server.wait_closed())
        loop.close()


server(('', 25000))
```

This server runs perfectly well if you netcat to port 25000 and start entering in numbers. However if you start a long running calculation (say 35), no other calculations will run until the first completes. In fact, additional connections won't even be processed.

I know that the event loop is feeding back the yields from recursive `fib` calls, so control has to be falling all the way down. But I thought that the loop would process the other calls in the I/O queues (such as spawning a second `fib_handler`) before "trampolining" back to the fib function.

I'm sure I must be misunderstanding something or that there is some kind of bug I'm overlooking but I can't for the life of me find it.

Any insight you can provide will be much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. If the coroutune never calls a future, the loop treats it as a plain coroutine and doesn't wrap it in a task, it just blasts through the calls at once. `asyncio.async()`\\ `asynicio.ensure_future()` wraps the coroutine in a future manually, so it get's added to the queue. Wrapping them did work, by the way. If you connect with another client during a long calculation, you can run other calcs on the 2nd client. If I did some refactoring and used callbacks, I think I could run multiple calculations in a single session. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you're calling `yield from fib(n)` inside of `fib_handler`. Including `yield from` means that `fib_handler` will block until the call to `fib(n)` is complete, which means it can't handle any input you provide while `fib` is running. You would have this problem even if all you did was I/O inside of `fib`. To fix this, you should use `asyncio.async(fib(n))` (or preferably, `asyncio.ensure_future(fib(n))`, if you have a new enough version of Python) to schedule `fib` with the event loop, without actually blocking `fib_handler`. From there, you can use `Future.add_done_callback` to write the result to the client when it's ready:

```
import asyncio
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

@asyncio.coroutine
def fib(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    a = yield from fib(n-1)
    b = yield from fib(n-2)
    return a + b

def do_it(writer, result):
    writer.write('{}\n'.format(result.result()).encode('ascii'))
    asyncio.async(writer.drain())

@asyncio.coroutine
def fib_handler(reader, writer):
    print('Connection from : {}'.format(writer.transport.get_extra_info('peername')))
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        req = yield from reader.readline()
        if not req:
            break
        print(req)
        n = int(req)
        result = asyncio.async(fib(n))
        # Write the result to the client when fib(n) is done.
        result.add_done_callback(partial(do_it, writer))
    writer.close()
    print("Closed")
```

That said, this change alone still won't completely fix the problem; while it will allow multiple clients to connect and issue commands concurrently, a single client will still get synchronous behavior. This happens because when you call `yield from coro()` directly on a coroutine function, control isn't given back to the event loop until `coro()` (or another coroutine called by `coro`) actually executes some non-blocking I/O. Otherwise, Python will just execute `coro` without yielding control. This is a useful performance optimization, since giving control to the event loop when your coroutine isn't actually going to do blocking I/O is a waste of time, especially given Python's high function call overhead.

In your case, `fib` never does any I/O, so once you call `yield from fib(n-1)` inside of `fib` itself, the event loop never gets to run again until its done recursing, which will block `fib_handler` from reading any subsequent input from the client until the call to `fib` is done. Wrapping *all* your calls to `fib` in `asyncio.async` guarantees that control is given to the event loop each time you make a `yield from asyncio.async(fib(...))` call. When I made this change, in addition to using `asyncio.async(fib(n))` in `fib_handler`, I was able to process multiple inputs from a single client concurrently. Here's the full example code:

```
import asyncio
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

@asyncio.coroutine
def fib(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    a = yield from fib(n-1)
    b = yield from fib(n-2)
    return a + b

def do_it(writer, result):
    writer.write('{}\n'.format(result.result()).encode('ascii'))
    asyncio.async(writer.drain())

@asyncio.coroutine
def fib_handler(reader, writer):
    print('Connection from : {}'.format(writer.transport.get_extra_info('peername')))
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        req = yield from reader.readline()
        if not req:
            break
        print(req)
        n = int(req)
        result = asyncio.async(fib(n))
        result.add_done_callback(partial(do_it, writer))
    writer.close()
    print("Closed")
```

Input/Output on client-side:

```
dan@dandesk:~$ netcat localhost 25000
35 # This was input
4  # This was input
8  # output
24157817 # output
```

Now, even though this works, I wouldn't use this implementation, since its doing a bunch of CPU-bound work in a single-threaded program that also wants to serve I/O in that same thread. This isn't going to scale very well, and won't have ideal performance. Instead, I'd recommend using `loop.run_in_executor` to run the calls to `fib` in a background process, which allows the asyncio thread to run at full capacity, and also allows us to scale the calls to `fib` across multiple cores:

```
import asyncio
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def fib(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 1
    a = fib(n-1)
    b = fib(n-2)
    return a + b

def do_it(writer, result):
    writer.write('{}\n'.format(result.result()).encode('ascii'))
    asyncio.async(writer.drain())

@asyncio.coroutine
def fib_handler(reader, writer):
    print('Connection from : {}'.format(writer.transport.get_extra_info('peername')))
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(8)  # 8 Processes in the pool
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        req = yield from reader.readline()
        if not req:
            break
        print(req)
        n = int(req)
        result = loop.run_in_executor(executor, fib, n)
        result.add_done_callback(partial(do_it, writer))
    writer.close()
    print("Closed")
```

Comment: Thanks for the write up! My initial goal was simply to allow two clients to run a calculation at the same time, And wrapping the inner recursive calls (eg: `fib(n-1)`) with the `async/ensure_future` was sufficient to get that done. When you gave me the idea to allow for concurrent calculations on a single connection, I ended up rewriting the handler as a custom `Protocol` to get some practice. I used an enclosure as a callback to do the output on the transport so very little had to actually be changed. I think  I've got a much better grasp on the difference between a task and a coroutine now.